# Necessary condition for a function to be one-to-one

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, complex-numbers, analytic-functions

A complex-valued function $f(z)$, is called one-to-one if $f(z_1) = f(z_2)$ implies $z_1 = z_2$.

The following statement is from Saff's Complex Analysis book.

> If $f$ is analytic at $z_{0}$ and $f'\left(z_{0}\right) \neq
>  0$, then there is an open disk $D$ centered at $z_{0}$ such that $f$
> is one-to-one on $D$.

The proof is as follows which I don't quite understand how the first implication is obtained and how the second implication leads to function being one-to-one. Any help in understanding this is much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: It is basic courtesy in this site to upvote and accept answers. Not only does that remove the question from the unanswered category but that is also the only way you reward the person who took time to answer your doubt and query. A "thanks for the answer" reply does not do any good. You have not done so in many of your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- $\frac{|f’(z_0)|}{2}$ is a positive number. So, you can take this as your “$\epsilon$” in the definition of $f’$ being continuous at $z_0$ (which it certainly is, since $f’$ is even better: analytic). This gives you the open disk $D$ centered at $z_0$.
- Consider any two points $z_1,z_2\in D$. The inequality in particular tells us that if $z_1\neq z_2$ then $|f(z_1)-f(z_2)|\geq |z_1-z_2|\cdot\frac{|f’(z_0)|}{2}>0$, since we have a product of two positive numbers, and hence $f(z_1)\neq f(z_2)$. This is the very definition of $f$ being injective (one-to-one) on $D$.

Another way of phrasing the injectivity argument from the inequality is to consider any two points $z_1,z_2\in D$ such that $f(z_1)=f(z_2)$. The inequality then implies $|z_1-z_2|\frac{|f’(z_0)|}{2}\leq |f(z_1)-f(z_2)|=0$, and since $|f’(z_0)|/2$ is non-zero, we can divide by it to get $|z_1-z_2|\leq 0$, and hence equality so $z_1=z_2$.

Comment: Thank you ! I know the first point is due to continuity so the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition holds but where's the $\delta$ ? 

I see that the second point is the contrapositive of the 1-1 definition I mentioned at the begining.

Comment: @Eureka I’m not going to answer that. You tell me what happens to $\delta$. Apply the definition. What does it tell you? Therefore…